How to share a service from host to remote in a micro frontend architecture?
I have a service in my host application that I would like to use in my remote (MFE) application. These 2 applications are hosted in different repositories
E.g. in my remote application
this.hostAppService.help();

How can I go about sharing this between the 2 applications? No state or anything will be handled via this service, just some simple helper functions.
Any ideas on how this can be done? I looked online and it seems libraries are an option but I would like to avoid that.
